# Having trouble aligning and increasing the width of my toggle navbar

Tags: html, css

I created a toggle navbar, where a menu and animation appear whenever the button is clicked. However, I'm having trouble with a few parts.

1. My content isn't aligning on the right side of the page, mainly the button itself.
2. I'm struggling to get the background of my menu (the lavender) to fill the full width and height of the page when it appears.

I've tried several methods, including 'float: right', 'width: 100vw', 'height: 100vh', andm more, but no luck.

Below is my code, as well as a link to essentially the look I'm trying to achieve. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Example: http://madetogether.com.au/case-study/sprout/

```
<!-- HTML -->
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
 <nav role="navigation">
  <div id="menuToggle">
    <input type="checkbox" />
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#page1" class="nav-link">
      Services
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#page3" class="nav-link">
      About
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#page4" class="nav-link">
      Contact
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
/* CSS */
/* Navigation Bar */
#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em; 
  z-index: 1; 
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  /* top: -7px;
  left: -5px;  */
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0; 
  z-index: 2; 
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em; 
  z-index: 1;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0; 
  z-index: 2; 
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
    transform-origin: 4px 0px;
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
            background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
            opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  background: lavender;
  opacity: .85;
    list-style-type: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;  
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}

#menu li {
  padding: .5em 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: right;
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul {
  transform: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the menu icon span with outer div and add float right to it and for checkbox use right 0

Following is the updated code

### UPDATE

I tried my level best to get the 100% height background using CSS, but failed. So I have tricked it with JavaScript.

```js
  function toggleHeight(){
      var navElement = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0];
      navElement.classList.toggle("fullHeight");

      var menuElement = document.getElementById("menu");
      menuElement.classList.toggle("fullHeight");
    
      var menuToggleElement = document.getElementById("menuToggle");
      menuToggleElement.classList.toggle("fullHeight");
  }
```

```css
#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em; 
  z-index: 1; 
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  /* top: -7px;
  left: -5px;  */
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0; 
  z-index: 2; 
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em; 
  z-index: 1;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  right: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0; 
  z-index: 2; 
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
    transform-origin: 4px 0px;
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
            background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
            opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  background: lavender;
  opacity: .85;
    list-style-type: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;  
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}

#menu li {
  padding: .5em 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: right;
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul {
  transform: none;
}     
.menuIcon {
    float: right;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

.fullHeight {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <div id="menuToggle">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleHeight()"/>
    <div class="menuIcon">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#page1" class="nav-link">
      Services
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#page3" class="nav-link">
      About
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#page4" class="nav-link">
      Contact
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Using your code, I was able to get the toggle navbar on the right side, but the lavender background still isn't fitting the full width and height of the website.

Comment: @GalaXee95 Check the updated answer, I have added some javascript to achieve the 100% background

Comment: It still doesn't work. I don't know why, but I've tried numerous times with your updated code :( Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: Sorry I was not able to help you last few days, Can you please share what you have implemented till now. (A Codepen link will work for me)

Comment: No worries, I really appreciate the help! I will try and get something running on Codepen. I will keep you posted.